# Send XMPP (Smack) Message

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

Ok, the problem should be trivial but I can't get to the bottom of it.

I have two users A & B

Their JID's for this example will be A@123 and B@123 where 123 is the IP of the server.

I'm sending a message from A->B using the following code:

```
   chat = chatmanager.createChat(username,
   new MessageListener() {
      public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {}});
   String sendUsername = username + "@123";
   Message msgObj = new Message(sendUsername, Message.Type.chat);
   msgObj.setBody(message);

   chat.sendMessage(msgObj);
```

I've hardcoded the IP so that I'm 100% sure that I attach the "@123" at the end of the nickname so there are no incorrect JIDs.

So A@123 sends msgObj to B@123.  This is how I understood XMPP messaging to work.  That you can't send from A->B but it must be A@123 -> B@123.

However, my server seems to think otherwise.  It continuously informs me of the following error:

```
 2010.12.27 19:02:52 [org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalOutgoingServerSession
 .createOutgoingSession(LocalOutgoingServerSession.java:258)] Error trying to 
 connect to remote server: A(DNS lookup: A:5269) 
 java.net.UnknownHostException: A
```

In both A and B's roster on the Openfire server, they have each other as a contact with the proper JIDs (username@123).

Can anyone provide some insight?  I'm lost.

**Edit**

I'm trying to use Wireshark to catch the XML sent to and from the Openfire server to determine if the recipient of the message is named properly (A@123 instead of A).

Upon using Wireshark, I received this as the XML being transferred:

```
\302\3469\223\341\3429\000\000\000\000\377\377
```

I have disabled SSL, I have connected un-securely.  I'm not sure why I'm getting SSL type XML, is that what it is?

Comment: This can only be caused by you sending something to A instead of A@123. Check the XML that you are actually sending to the server (using Wireshark if Smack/Openfire don't provide any stream inspection).

Comment: Sounds good Matt.  Didn't think of Wireshark before.  I couldn't understand how Smack would send to A if I had hardcoded the @IP.  I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Wireshark isn't providing any relevant information.  I believe it is because I am connecting on port 5222.  The XML it gives me it a series of numbers instead of actual XML. Not sure how to get past that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the answer to this problem was something that was just overlooked.

In the first line of code:

```
 chat = chatmanager.createChat(username, new MessageListener() {
            public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {}
      });
```

I didn't make the variable "username" have the proper IP extension.  So it was merely "A" instead of "A@123"

Moving "sendUsername" to the top and Changing "username" to "sendUsername" makes everything work great :)

Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using IP addresses is almost always more confusing than you think it is.

There's a good chance you have OpenFire misconfigured, so that the IP address isn't a valid hostname.  Go into the admin console, under "System Properties", and make sure that the `xmpp.domain` property is set to your IP address.

Comment: Joe, The xmpp.domain is set to 123 (following the same IP system I was using in the example), so it is correct.