# Openfire send message using rest api in php

Tags: openfire, sendmessage

I am using openfire. I am able to add users and groups. But now stuck at send message from one user to another. I was going through libraries but not found any suitable. I tried xmpp bosh library but getting error:

```
"message": "Declaration of XMPPHP_BOSH::connect($server, $wait = '1', $session = false) should be compatible with XMPPHP_XMLStream::connect($timeout = 30, $persistent = false, $sendinit = true)",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540012/5853262) may help you.

Answer (score -2):

The REST API Plugin does not provide the feature you are looking fore (1:1 messaging). The REST API Plugin is made to manage the Openfire Instance (Users, Groups, Channels etc.)

To send one to one messages, you could use the openfire chat plugin. (https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-chat)

**Example:**

```
POST /restapi/v1/chat/{streamid}/messages/{destination}

{
   "body" : "desired message"
}
```